# does flutter support rstp/rtmp video player?

Tags: video, flutter

I found flutter video_player based on AVPlayer in IOS, which does not support rtsp url.
Can anyone help me know how to play a video with format like 'rstp/rtmp' in flutter?

Comment: I am also interested on it!

Comment: Did you find a solution for RTSP?

Answer (score 1):

Flutter Vlc player package can handle rtsp streams.

[flutter_vlc_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player)

This is the example from the readme section, change value of "urlToStreamVideo" for your source address to test it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';

class ExampleVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleVideoState createState() => _ExampleVideoState();
}

class _ExampleVideoState extends State<ExampleVideo> {
  final String urlToStreamVideo = 'http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4';
  final VlcPlayerController controller = new VlcPlayerController(
      // Start playing as soon as the video is loaded.
      onInit: (){
          controller.play();
      }  
  );
  final int playerWidth = 640;
  final int playerHeight = 360;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox(
            height: playerHeight,
            width: playerWidth,
            child: new VlcPlayer(
                aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                url: urlToStreamVideo,
                controller: controller,
                placeholder: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Inviting you to improve the plugin https://github.com/oneeyedraven/flutter_rtsp_ffmpeg which support RTSP streaming on flutter with minimum latency. Since this is a very naive plugin, support and help is required to make this perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement where I had to display a stream from an IP Camera with minimum latency. I tried with lot of open-source players but none of them was able to stream with a latency around 200ms.

Searching thoroughly over the internet, I found a few examples which involved using Native FFMPEG code on Android to receive and decode the RTSP stream and render it directly over the SurfaceView using NativeWindow interface. Following this, I was able to get a stream with minimum latency.

Following this, I have put across the current implementation (which is very naive but will help to get started) in a flutter plug-in, code to which is available at [Github][1]

It would be great if we can improve this plugin further and make it perfect for a production release.

PS: The plugin currently supports Android only, but I am hopeful, the iOS version can be developed on similar lines.
[1]: https://github.com/oneeyedraven/flutter_rtsp_ffmpeg